# S7 Edge: Internet randomly stops working until reboot

Tags: reboot, samsung-galaxy-s-7-edge

My Samsung S7 Edge (Android 7.0) has lately developed the following problem: every once in a while, at seemingly random times, the internet stops working - in any app, and both on WiFi and on mobile. Connectivity is only back to normal when I restart the phone.

This occurs maybe once every 2 days or so, and is as you can imagine very disruptive. I've let it update the OS but even the most recent update did not fix (it may not even acknowledge) this bug.

Any ideas?

Comment: Does this happen in safe mode also?

Comment: I was going to try now, but I don't see a Safe Mode among my phone's options!..

Comment: It's not a built in option. Follow instructions [here](https://support.t-mobile.com/docs/DOC-28008). If it is fine safe mode then it indicates that some installed app is the culprit

Comment: Did you tried cleaning cache and dalvik from recovery sometimes it gets messed up after OS update..?

Comment: Here are a few things to try: i) disabling ipv6, ii) switching to 2g/3g and back if the issue resurfaces. if it persists take  the device to service centre for inspection

Comment: Please advice me, if the mentioned points solved your issue, so I can put it as answer to help other users

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following workarounds have been shown either to temporarily fix the connection drop issues or provide long-term solution (because this problem has been suggested to be attributed to a bug in hardware that may need specialised repair)

1. **Disabling ipv6 settings**

   - Go to Settings >> Mobile Settings >> APN settings and edit your APN-settings. Disable/remove IPv6 and save it.
2. **Toggling to 2g/3g to bypass  connection drops**

   - As the issue has also been reported to have been attributed to a bug in LTE radio, changing the setting from lte mode to edge/hpsa mode can temporarily resolve the drop issues, and saves from rebooting device.

*One user has also reported to have sent their device to service centre to get LTE calibration done, I have suspicion that it may be band incompatibility issue)*

Other workarounds

- reseting APN settings to default
- switching SIM cards
- send the device to service centre to get it checked and perhaps fixed.

Credits

- [Galaxy S7 LTE problems](https://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-s7/help/galaxy-s7-lte-problems-t3336923/page3)

Comment: haven't yet had time to try all of these but I think your answer deserves the bounty nonetheless, thanks!

Comment: Thanks for that!  Please feel free to post own answer if you find anything useful, remember you can always un-accept the answer if a better solution comes, BTW thanks for bounty!!

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue with my s7 (non-edge) when I had data saver turned on.  Turning this off solved the issue for me.  If it is restricted to certain applications, you may be able to add them to the exception list and try.

The data saver setting is under settings -> Connections -> Data usage -> Data Saver.

Comment: many thanks for your input. unfortunately this wasn't the case here, as i never turned that option on..